# chart.js horizontal stack bar not showing expcected result

Tags: chart.js

i have a project in  real time calculation project does not stack correctly ,i have 3 dataset stack one by one but it shows only two data in my chart

```
<div class="graph_container">
<canvas ref="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>        
</div>
```

Option for horizontal  stack bar format with time

```
var options={
        responsive:true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false, 
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          x: {   
            offset: true,   
            stacked: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
            unit:'hour'
            },
            min:  moment(String(todayStartTime)),
            max: moment(String(todayEndTime))
    
            // max:  moment().add(8, 'hours')
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            offset: true
          }
        }
      }
```

**My Dataset**

```
const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "T1"+moment(todayStartTime).add(0.5,'hours'),
      data: [
        {
        x: moment(todayStartTime).add(0.5,'hours'),
        y: 0
      },
      ],
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    {
      label: "T2"+moment(todayStartTime).add(2,'hours'),
      data: [{
        x: moment(todayStartTime).add(2,'hours'),
        y: 0
      }],
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
    {
      label: "T3"+moment(todayStartTime).add(3,'hours'),
      data: [
        {
  x: moment(todayStartTime).add(3,'hours'),
        y: 0
      }],
      backgroundColor: "orange"
    },  
    
  ]
};
```

Chart js

```
var $vm=this;
const ctx =this.$refs.myChart;

var todayStartTime=new moment('2022-10-19 08:00:00 am')
var todayEndTime=new moment('2022-10-19 03:00:00 pm')

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options
};

 new Chart(ctx,config);
```

Output  (First Dataset only Correct)
[image]

it showing only first dataset is correct other dataset wrong and some missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a stacked x axis, this means that instead of the value starting at the origin it starts where the first bar ends. To resolve this issue you need to set the `options.scales.x.stacked` to `false` or dont set it since false is the default.

Example:

```js
var todayStartTime = new moment('2022-10-19 08:00:00');
var todayEndTime = new moment('2022-10-19 15:00:00');

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  indexAxis: 'y',
  scales: {
    x: {
      offset: false,
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'hour'
      },
      min: todayStartTime,
      max: todayEndTime
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
      offset: true
    }
  }
};
const data = {
  datasets: [{
      label: "T1" + moment(todayStartTime).add(0.5, 'hours'),
      data: [{
        x: moment(todayStartTime).add(0.5, 'hours'),
        y: 0
      }],
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    {
      label: "T2" + moment(todayStartTime).add(2, 'hours'),
      data: [{
        x: moment(todayStartTime).add(2, 'hours'),
        y: 0
      }],
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
    {
      label: "T3" + moment(todayStartTime).add(3, 'hours'),
      data: [{
        x: moment(todayStartTime).add(3, 'hours'),
        y: 0
      }],
      backgroundColor: "orange"
    },
  ]
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options
};

new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@1.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400" />
```

Credits go to Stockinail that answered this question already on github: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10815

Comment: How to place label center of each colour?

Comment: You will need the datalabels plugin for that: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/